# How to join multiple tables in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a database that contains the point of sales data for multiple marinas across different countries. There are tables set up to drop in the raw POS data, one for each currency. Each currency is set up under a unique Database Code. I am running multiple queries off each table. One of those quires joins the following table "T_BLG" to pull in the unique Boat Length Group by Location Code.

T_BLG

| Location Code | Min Boat Length | Max Boat Length | Boat Length Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AYH | 0.00 | 79.00 | 0-79 |
| AYH | 80.00 | 120.00 | 80-120 |
| AYH | 121.00 | 99,999.00 | 121+ |
| OIP | 0.00 | 100.00 | 0-100 |
| OIP | 101.00 | 200.00 | 101-200 |
| OIP | 201.00 | 99,999.00 | 201+ |

I was able to Left Join the query to the T_BLG using the following statement.

```
SELECT q_Step2_AMR.*, 

t_BLG.[Boat Length Group], 

[Database Code] & [HS Boat Code] AS [Unique Vessel ID By DB]

FROM q_Step2_AMR LEFT JOIN t_BLG 

ON q_Step2_AMR.[Location Code] = t_BLG.[Location Code]

WHERE (((q_Step2_AMR.[HS Boat Length 2]) Between [Min Boat Length] And [Max Boat Length]));
```

Recently I had the request to bring in the Mega Attribute Length. I set up a new table for these criteria and called the table "T_MEGA".

T_MEGA

| Database Code | Min Boat Length | Max Boat Length | Mega Attribute Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMR | 0.00 | 150.00 | 0-150 |
| AMR | 151.00 | 249.00 | 151-249 |
| AMR | 250.00 | 99,999.00 | 250+ |
| PCM | 0.00 | 150.00 | 0-150 |
| PCM | 151.00 | 249.00 | 151-249 |
| PCM | 250.00 | 99,999.00 | 250+ |

Below would be my desired output with the first four fields being the q_Step2_AMR:

| Location Code | Database Code | HS Boat Code | HS Boat Length 2 | Unique Vessel ID by DB | Boat Length Group | Mega Attribute Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AYH | AMR | A0001 | 50.00 | AMRA0001 | 0-79 | 0-150 |
| OIP | PCM | A0002 | 500.00 | PCMA0002 | 201+ | 250+ |

I am able to use a UNION ALL as followed:

```
SELECT q_Step2_AMR.*, t_BLG.[Boat Length Group], 
[Database Code] & [HS Boat Code] AS [Unique Vessel ID By DB]
FROM 
q_Step2_AMR 
LEFT JOIN 
t_BLG 
ON q_Step2_AMR.[Location Code] = t_BLG.[Location Code]
WHERE (((q_Step2_AMR.[HS Boat Length 2]) Between [Min Boat Length] And [Max Boat Length])) 

UNION ALL SELECT q_Step2_AMR.*, t_MEGA.[Mega Attribute Length],
"" AS [Unique Vessel ID By DB]
FROM 
q_Step2_AMR 
LEFT JOIN 
t_MEGA 
ON q_Step2_AMR.[Database Code] = t_MEGA.[Database Code] 
WHERE (((q_Step2_AMR.[HS Boat Length 2]) Between [Min Boat Length] And [Max Boat Length]));
```

However, since the Union All is using the q_Step2_AMR in both Select statements I am essentially duplicated my data. Is there a better option than using the UNION ALL?

Comment: What did you try? What do you mean by 'merge' - UNION or JOIN? Show sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: I tried to use the UNION ALL. However since I am using the AS to brining in a [Unique Vessel ID by DB] in the first SELECT its causing a difference in columns. If I remove the AS the query works. See below for what I attempted unsuccessfully. I am unable to provide a clean output as the data I'm working in has over 70 fields.

Comment: SELECT q_Step2_AMR.*, t_BLG.[Boat Length Group], [Database Code] & [HS Boat Code] AS [Unique Vessel ID By DB]

FROM q_Step2_AMR LEFT JOIN t_BLG ON q_Step2_AMR.[Location Code] = t_BLG.[Location Code]

WHERE (((q_Step2_AMR.[HS Boat Length 2]) Between [Min Boat Length] And [Max Boat Length]))

UNION ALL

SELECT q_Step3_AMR.*, t_MEGA.[Mega Attribute Length]

FROM q_Step3_AMR LEFT JOIN t_MEGA ON q_Step3_AMR.[Database Code] = t_MEGA.[Database Code]

WHERE (((q_Step3_AMR.[HS Boat Length 2]) Between [Min Boat Length1] And [Max Boat Length1]));

Comment: You should edit question to show attempted SQL. Also, provide data as already suggested. Probably don't need all 70 fields to illustrate requirements. If second query doesn't have corresponding field, use NULL in that position.

Comment: I have edited my question to provided the requested data. Thank you for your assistance so far, please advise if there is any additional information I should be providing.

Answer (score 0):

The UNION ALL code you posted in your comment does not work (as you point out) because both SELECTS have a different number of fields. To make it work you only need to add an additional constant field to the second SELECT, being of the same data type as the field [Unique Vessel ID By DB], which seems to be a string. The code would therefore be:

```
   SELECT q_Step2_AMR.*, t_BLG.[Boat Length Group], [Database Code] & [HS Boat Code] AS [Unique Vessel ID By DB]
   FROM 
      q_Step2_AMR 
   LEFT JOIN 
      t_BLG 
   ON q_Step2_AMR.[Location Code] = t_BLG.[Location Code] 
   WHERE (((q_Step2_AMR.[HS Boat Length 2]) Between [Min Boat Length] And [Max Boat Length])) 

UNION ALL 

   SELECT q_Step3_AMR.*, t_MEGA.[Mega Attribute Length], "" AS [Unique Vessel ID By DB]
   FROM 
      q_Step3_AMR 
   LEFT JOIN 
      t_MEGA 
   ON q_Step3_AMR.[Database Code] = t_MEGA.[Database Code] 
   WHERE (((q_Step3_AMR.[HS Boat Length 2]) Between [Min Boat Length1] And [Max Boat Length1]));
```

Comment: Don't need same data type constant, can use NULL. First SELECT defines field types and names. The AS alias is not needed in subsequent SELECT statements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am very new to the form and still working through the learning curve and was not able to figure out how to respond to your answer with an updated statement without exceeding the character limit. I have edited my question with my current Statement. Sorry for any confusion and thank you for your assistance so far!